# Question regarding 74ls90's and 74ls93

Tags: design

I'm trying to build a circuit that counts the number of pulses and displays it on a seven segment display.

For this, I need to make use of a 74ls90, however I cannot get one of these, as they are out of stock at my university's circuit shop.

They have supplied me with a 74ls93 however, and said that it should work with this.

Is it possible to rather use the 74ls93 in a basic counter circuit?

Comment: Read the data sheets for the devices first then ask a question based on what you don't understand.

Comment: 74x90 is a decade counter while 74x93 is a binary counter. You would have to figure out how to asynchronously reset the '93 so you don't get counts 0xA and above.

Comment: When the counter reaches 9 (1001)you want the next count to change it to 0000. The 7493 changes to a 10 count = 1010. If you AND the two 1's you will get an output when the 10 count occurs - this can be used to reset the counter to 0000. THere will be circuits onlime that do this OR ask again if more help needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it'll work to a point - specifically, until the count reaches 9.

The 74LS90 is a Binary Coded Decimal (BCD) counter, so it only counts valid decimal numbers, i.e. up to 9 (1001 in binary) before resetting back to 0.

The 74LS93 is a binary counter, so it will carry on past 9 and count up to 15 (F in hexadecimal or 1111 in binary). That will probably confuse whatever you're using to display the result and will prevent you properly cascading multiple counters to produce displays with more than one digit.

There are also two "Set-to-nine" inputs on the 74LS90 used to set its value directly to 9, these should have been tied low if you didn't need them but should be left unconnected on the 74LS93.

Comment: "There are also two Set inputs on the 74LS90 that can be used to set its value directly to 9, these should be tied low." ... Actually they are Reset inputs and they could be quite useful (see Spehro's comment). [74LS90/93 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls93.pdf)

Comment: But they refer to them as "set-to-nine" inputs... updated.

Comment: The OP can't get a 74LS90. The question is about substituting with a 74LS93 and those only have Reset pins (there are no set-to-nine pins on that device). (sorry I do see that you mentioned 74ls90, not 74ls93, but as I said the OP can't get that part)

Comment: Good point, @Tut - guess they're not going to be useful after all. Updated again.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you must have it roll from 9 to back to 0 on the next count. If you are allowed to have it count to 15 rather than 9 then it will work fine. It will count from 0 to 9 normally, then to hexidecimal states A, B, C, D, E, F then back to 0. Also, it would be interesting to know whether your 7-segment display will properly display digits above 9 or if it will display nonsense.